# Sump Pump Check Valve on Washing Laundry Machine

Tags: plumbing, water

I am a resident and my apartment manager purchased a Everbuilt THD1020 (In-Line Sump Pump Check Valve) , and installed in the back hose of our washing machine. The back hose would leak detergent soap and water. Is it a good practice to install In-Line check valves like this on laundry machines? The original hose kept leaking water/soap, so decided to add this.

** My main question is, does it make dirt/waste come back into the washing machine itself, and dirty the clothes more? I am a resident and curious about this. I was telling my apartment manager to look into this article, about why its leaking. Anyways, my main concern is how it'll affect clothing quality or cleanliness etc.

Plumbing reasons: https://www.artplumbingandac.com/plumbing/what-to-do-about-a-leaking-washing-machine-hose/

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-4-to-1-1-2-in-ABS-In-Line-Sump-Pump-Check-Valve-THD1020/205616001

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where was the hose leaking?  Washing machine drain hoses are suppose to have an air gap inside the building/house drain pipe, so they don't need check valves.  Check valves would probably fail quite fast from the soap/dirt/fibres.

Comment: Im not sure where its leaking, around the back hose where the sump check valve was installed, how about my main question?  does it make dirt/waste come back into the washing machine itself, and dirty the clothes more. cc @crip659 thanks

Comment: why would you think that the checkvalve would make dirty water come back into the machine? ... the checkvalve's purpose is to prevent water from backing up

Comment: It should not make dirty water come in to the washer any more than the hose without it.  If the drain pipe has a blockage in it so water does not drain as fast, it might even help to prevent it, but it should not be necessary and will not fix the problem.  The cause of the leaking should be fixed, which I think is causing the water to back up.

Comment: hi @crip659 I was telling my apartment manager to look into this article, about why its leaking, anyways, my main concern is how it will affect clothing quality or cleaniless etc, thanks again for the advice !